# update jquery span from other one

Tags: jquery

i have a form like this

```
area: <input type="text" id="area" name="area" class="area"  value="0"/>
Price per square meter: <input type="text" id="square" name="square" class="square"       value="0"/>
Total Price: <span class="total"></span>
25% of total price:  <span class="25total"></span>
```

and a script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.fn.priceTotal = function() {
var valueArea = $("#area").val(); 
var valueAreaFinal = parseFloat(valueArea, 10);

var valueSquare = $("#square").val(); 
var valueSquareFinal = parseFloat(valueSquare, 10);

var TotalPriceFinal = valueAreaFinal * valueSquareFinal;
return TotalPriceFinal;
    };


    $(document).ready(function() {
$('input.area').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('span.total').html( $('input.price').priceTotal() );
});
$('input.square').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('span.total').html( $('input.price').priceTotal() );
});
    }); 

</script>
```

With this form when i put area and price per square meter, the total price is caclulated automatically.
my problem now, how to calculate the 25% of total price in another span called 25total

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but couldn't you just copy-paste what you have, then change the span you're writing to, then just divide your priceTotal() return value by 4?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but what's the point of making `priceTotal` a method on *all* jQuery objects (with `$.fn.priceTotal`)? You're not even referencing `this` inside that function. You're probably better off with a basic JavaScript function such as `function priceTotal() { ... }`.

Comment: in fact it's first time i use jquery, i find this plugin in the web and i don't know how to change it. thanks for your advices, i will read documentation to understand this langage.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.fn.priceTotal = function() {
var valueArea = $("#area").val(); 
var valueAreaFinal = parseFloat(valueArea, 10);

var valueSquare = $("#square").val(); 
var valueSquareFinal = parseFloat(valueSquare, 10);

var TotalPriceFinal = valueAreaFinal * valueSquareFinal;
return TotalPriceFinal;
    };


    $(document).ready(function() {
$('input.area').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('span.total').html( $('input.price').priceTotal() );
    $('span.25total').html( $('input.price').priceTotal() / 4 );
});
$('input.square').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('span.total').html( $('input.price').priceTotal() );
    $('span.25total').html( $('input.price').priceTotal() / 4 );
});
    }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're using the keyup event, you're going to want priceTotal to be as efficient as possible, and not creating variables every time it's called. Go for this solution:

```
  $.fn.priceTotal = function() {
        return parseFloat($("#area").val(), 10) * parseFloat($("#square").val(), 10)
    };


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.area, input.square').bind('keyup', function() {
      var priceTotal = $('input.price').priceTotal();
      $('span.total').html(priceTotal);
      $('.25total').text(parseInt(priceTotal) / 4));
   }
});

</script>
```